# Split by number of pages for dynamic report in itext - 5000 pages generated on the fly

Tags: itext

I'm creating a PDF using itext and finally closing the document with document.close(). After generating the pdf, there are several ways to split the up.

The problem is i need to split the pdf before creating as a whole in the first place.

Is there a way to split by number of pages dynamically or control by number of pages?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes and no. How are you creating your document? It's possible if you check the current page number before adding objects with `document.add()` and then decide to `close()` the document, and start a new one. However, if you create on large table, add this to the `document`, it will be distributed over different pages without you being able to control the distribution over different documents.

Comment: I'm adding a dynamic table with html tags..I'm not adding the page with addNewPage() alone....so in such a case how to calculate the page number

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. In this case, the answer is "No": you can't split the document while creating it. You have to create the document first, then split it in a second go.