# Is it possible to Split by number of pages for dynamic html tables in itext

Tags: itext

We are creating dynamic html tables in itext.

is there a possibility to split by number of pages or calculate the pages before the entire PDF is being written to the disk?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35220160): if you create a PDF using iText from HTML tables, you can't "split on the fly". You have to create the full document first, then split it in a second go.

However, this doesn't mean that you have to create the document on disk. You can easily write the full document to memory first, and then write the different parts to disk in the second go.